# Recursive Hard Links in dired

Tags: dired

If I want to do recursive hardlinks of a directory I have to use `cp -r -l dir` in bash instead of `ln -h`. How do I replicate this in dired, because `dired-do-hardlink` uses `ln` underneath?

I can use `M-! cp -r -l dir` but I would like to not have to treat directories differently when linking files around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`diredp-do-hardlink-recursive`**, from library [**Dired+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

```
diredp-do-hardlink-recursive is an interactive compiled Lisp function
in `dired+.el'.

(diredp-do-hardlink-recursive &optional IGNORE-MARKS-P)

Add hard links for marked files, including those in marked subdirs.
Like `dired-do-hardlink', but act recursively on subdirs to pick up the
files to link.

The files included are those that are marked in the current Dired
buffer, or all files in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way.

With a prefix argument, ignore all marks - include all files in this
Dired buffer and all subdirs, recursively.
```

Comment: It always impress me that you will know an answer to almost everything, Drew.

Comment: If I install `dired+` using `package-install` I lose default dired behavior. How do I just use dired as a library of functions?

Comment: You lose what default Dired behavior? Dired+ is a superset of Dired. Please be specific - perhaps the same behavior is there, but not where you are looking for it.

Comment: @ReneFroger: Not at all. I know nothing about *most* of the things asked here - nothing about Org or Spacemacs or Prelude or AUCTex or.... I do know some things about a few parts of Emacs. Dired is one of those parts. Anyone would, after spending a lot of time trying to customize things - like you all are doing. Spend as much time with the Dired code as I have (over a long period of time) and you are bound to have picked up a few things. It's the same story for everyone, really.

Comment: It automatically toggled `dired-hide-details-mode`, so I just had to toggle it again with `(`. It does change the look and feel though too.

Comment: @salotz: Just customize option `diredp-hide-details-initially-flag`. Take a look also at other Dired+ options, including `diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag`. Advice: if you consider using library, always take a look at its doc or file header, or at least look at its user options.

Comment: @Drew I was kind of hoping for an answer that was less intrusive to my current settings, so that I don't have to spend time digging into customizing yet more options unrelated to my original problem. I appreciate customization a whole lot and anticipate doing in the future with Dired+, but sometimes I just want something to be easy and get out of my way!

Comment: If you don't want to load Dired+ for some reason then you can dig out the relevant code from it and use that. Command **`diredp-do-hardlink-recursive`** is what you need, but it is defined in terms of `diredp-get-confirmation-recursive` and `diredp-do-create-files-recursive` (which is defined using `diredp-get-files`).